# Change to vs Change with?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I have looked on the internet regarding this issue and could not find a definitive answer so I posted the question here.

Which one do I use if I want to change something to something else?

Example imperative sentence:

`Change that code with/to? this code.`

In this instance - change to or change with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which one do I use if I want to **change something to something else**?

I think you may have unintentionally answered your own question here.

Yes, you do want to say "change to" and not "change with".

"Change that code to this code" means "replace this code with this new code".

"Change that code with this code" could mean "execute this code in order to change that code" or "alter this code by using this other code to change it".